# How to get previous not NaN value of a pandas DataFrame, without apply, to calculate?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Without using apply (because dataframe is too big), how I can get the previous not NaN value of a specific column to use in a calc ?

For example, this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A',1,100],['B',2,None],['C',3,None],['D',4,182],['E',5,None]], columns=['A','B','C'])
   A  B      C
0  A  1  100.0
1  B  2    NaN
2  C  3    NaN
3  D  4  182.0
4  E  5    NaN
```

I need to calc the difference, in the column 'C' of the line 3 with the line 0.

The number of NaN values between the values is variable, then `.shift()` maybe is not applicable here (I think)

I need some like: `df['D'] = df.C - df.C[previous_not_nan]` (in the line 3 will be 82.

Comment: something like this: ``df.C - df.C[df.C.first_valid_index()]`` not scalable though when you have variable nulls. I'd suggest you add more rows with nulls, and an expected output dataframe. Nothing beats visuals, plus it allows for more tests, in terms of solutions provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) + [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html)

```
df['D'] = df['C'].dropna().diff()
```

---

```
   A  B      C     D
0  A  1  100.0   NaN
1  B  2    NaN   NaN
2  C  3    NaN   NaN
3  D  4  182.0  82.0
4  E  5    NaN   NaN
```